# Normal Equation in a special norm

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $m\ge n$. The normal equation for minimizing $\| Ax-b\|_2^2$ with respect to $x$ is $A^TAx=A^Tb$. Then derive the normal equation for minimizing $\| Ax-b\|_C^2$, where C is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $\| x\|_C^2=x^TCx$.

I don't know how to start with; can someone give me some hint about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and  $\mathbb{R}^m$ are column vectors. If you consider $f(y)=\|y\|_2^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ then the derivative is
$$
f'(y)=2(y_1,\dots,y_m) = 2y^\top.
$$
For $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $g(x)=Ax-b$ we have $g'(x)=A$. Now the chain rule gives
$$
(f\circ g)'(x)=2(Ax-b)^\top A.
$$
So, the critical points are those $x$ with $(Ax-b)^\top A=0$. Transposing leads to $A^\top(Ax-b)=0$, that is $A^\top Ax=A^\top b$.

For $C$ positive definite try to find the derivative of $x \mapsto x^\top C x$.